# Trying to send data from javascript to python POS odoo using rpc.query

Tags: javascript, python, rpc, odoo-13

I am trying to send my data in the list to their fields so i can retrieve them into another screen in same module / project.

The list i am trying to send :

```
var vals = {
                'token_number':Token,
                'partner_id':customer_name,
                'queue_line_ids':queue_lines,
            }
```

where **Token** is random number generated on custom_button click,**customer_name** is the id of customer obtained by "this.pos.get_order().cid" and **queuelines** is array of product and their info obtained from orderlines.

The `rpc.query` i wrote by referring to  point_of_sale in odoo13/addon/ :

```
 return rpc.query({
                model: 'pos.queue',
                method: 'create',
                args: [vals],

            }).then(function () {
                console.log("Success")
            }).catch(function (reason){
                var error = reason.message;
                console.log(error);
            });
```

The `pos.queue` in my module's model.py :

```
class POSOrderQueue(models.Model):
    _name = 'pos.queue'

    token_number = fields.Integer(string="Token Number", store=True)
    partner_id = fields.Char(store=True)
    pos_order_id = fields.Char(store=True)
    order_progress = fields.Selection([('in_queue', 'In Queue'),
                                       ('in_progress', 'In Progress'),
                                       ('done', 'Done')], string="Order progress", default='inqueue', store=True)
    no_items = fields.Integer(string='No of Items', store=True)
    queue_line_ids = fields.One2many('pos.queue.line', 'queue_id')




 def create(self):
        val = {
            "token_number": self.token_number,
            "partner_id": self.partner_id,
            "queue_line_ids": self.queue_line_ids,
        }

        self.env['pos.queue'].create(val)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes so i was finding solution to pass orderline data in my database along with other as i came a long way from time this question was passed so i felt obliged to share my findings and modification which enable to pass `token number` `Customer id` `Estimated time` & `status`.
Following are the modification i did so far
The list :

```
val_list = {
                        'token_number':Token,
                        'partner_id':customer_name,
                        'pos_order_id':torder.name,
                        'est_time':e_time,
                        'order_progress':torder.order_progress,
                        
                   };
```

where `torder` is `this.pos.get_order()`.
MY rpc query become like (thanks to my supervisor)

```
 return rpc.query({
                    model: 'pos.queue',
                    method: 'create_token',
                    args:[val_list],
                }).then(function () {
                    console.log("Success")
                }).catch(function (reason){
                    var error = reason.message;
                    console.log(error);
                });
```

the model became like:

```
class POSOrderQueue(models.Model):
    _name = 'pos.queue'

    token_number = fields.Integer(string="Token Number", store=True)
    partner_id = fields.Char(store=True)
    pos_order_id = fields.Char(store=True)
    est_time = fields.Text(string="estimated time", store=True)
    order_progress = fields.Selection([('in_queue', 'In Queue'),
                                       ('in_progress', 'In Progress'), ('cancel', 'Cancel'),
                                       ('done', 'Done')], string="Order progress", default='in_queue', store=True)
    no_items = fields.Integer(string='No of Items', store=True)
    queue_line_ids = fields.One2many('pos.queue.line', 'queue_id')

    @api.model
    def create_token(self, val_list):
        res = super(POSOrderQueue, self).create(val_list)
        print("yes working")
        return res

class POSOrderQueueLine(models.Model):
    _name = 'pos.queue.line'

    queue_id = fields.Many2one('pos.queue')
    product_name = fields.Char(store=True)
    product_quant = fields.Integer()
    product_price = fields.Float()

    def create(self, vals):
        res = super(POSOrderQueueLine, self).create(vals)
        return res
```

The problem is partially solved but i can't acheive my last objective which is to pass `orderline` data through rpc query into my model `pos.queue.line` so it can be viewable in my custom view of odoo13 which is like this
[screenshot of my view table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bzNs1.png)